# Queries execute via phpmyadmin but not via php script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I've got 2 mysql queries below and I try to execute them via php but syntax error appears. When I execute them via phpmyadmin it works like a charm showing proper results, can you help me with this?

```
DELETE a FROM wp_posts AS a INNER JOIN ( SELECT post_content, MIN( id ) AS min_id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY post_content HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1 ) AS b ON b.post_content = a.post_content AND b.min_id <> a.id AND a.post_type = 'post' AND a.post_status = 'publish';

DELETE FROM wp_posts

WHERE post_content NOT LIKE '%<img src=%'AND ID not in (select post_id as p from wp_postmeta where meta_key like '_wp_attached_file')

OR `post_title` like '%.png%'

OR post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 day);
```

Comment: post your PHP code and full error message

Comment: you cant put multiple queries in one execution. you can in phpmyadmin as it sees the colon and splits them

Comment: So do you have any idea how this query should look like with separators?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) if you want to use multiple statements in a query. There's more information in the [`Multiple Statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) page.

Note that "Use of the multiple statement with prepared statements is not supported." and so for that reason alone it's perhaps better to avoid the above function and stick to a single prepared query for each statement if using client-supplied parameters (e.g. request variables).